# On Debian Stretch, Nouveau drivers are getting my pc to freeze, had to install non-free NVIDIA packages on my system, any alternatives?

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

My main goal with Debian is to go 100% open source, but now my (sand) castle has just been kicked and colapsed. I've done my homework and troubleshooted every piece of hardware on my pc and it's not hardware, also done several fresh installs.

My pc only stopped freezing randomly when I installed closed source NVIDIA drivers. It worked fine on 8.8, but since I hopped on debian 9 it started with that odd occurrence.

Ubuntu and windows are working just fine on this machine and every piece of hardware passed stress testings.

Is there something I can do to still use nouveau or another driver without having to install closed source stuff?

Comment: It would be good to know which hardware. `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`

Comment: I am seeing kernel oopses (and freezing of the display) with the following: 
`04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 420] [10de:0de2] (rev a1)`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience video drivers often break from kernel updates. Try rebooting and choosing advanced boot options in grub and use an older kernel to boot normally. Then attempt to install the libre driver once more.